# Swift4 + FMDB - columnCount() Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int32'?

Tags: ios, swift4, fmdb

I am using FMDatabaseQueue for existing sqlite database in iOS. I just want to search data from database and convert the result to a dictionary Array. I have copied other's code in swift 3, but it didn't work.

It alerted that

columnCount() ========"Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int32'"

========================================================

```
func queryDB(sql: String) -> [[String: AnyObject]] {

   var array: [[String: AnyObject]] = [[String: AnyObject]]()

   SQLiteManager.shareInstance.dbQueue?.inDatabase { (db) in

        let dbResult: FMResultSet! = db.executeQuery(sql, withArgumentsIn: [])

        var dict: [String: AnyObject] = [String: AnyObject]()

        while dbResult.next() {

            let column = dbResult.columnCount()
            // Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int32'????

            for i in 0..<column {
                let key = dbResult.columnName(for: i)
                let value = dbResult.object(forColumnIndex: i)
                dict[key] = value               
            }
            array.append(dict)
        }   
    }  
    return array
}
```

========================================================

[What I want is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI472.png)

Thanks!

Comment: According to the error message, `columnCount` is a *property* of type Int32, not a method. Besides, what you need is likely to be the ready-made FMResultSet.resultDictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your generous advice. Many functions have been converted to properties in FMDB 2.7. It's so sad.